# Добраться до первого элемента в System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary

Tags: .net, c++, c#

Нужно из пары `<string, DateTime>` получить тот элемент, который был добавлен самым первым
в C++, используя map, я мог создать итератор и взять `myMap.begin()`. Помогите.

Comment: Предположу, что нужно что-то вроде

    dict.GetEnumerator().Current

Хотя, скорее всего, Dictionary не гарантирует упорядоченность элементов.

Comment: @Etki, есть SortedDictionary, но если не ошибаюсь, то он сортирует, вместо хранения в порядке добавления., спасибо

Comment: Первый элемент упорядоченной коллекции можно получить через LINQ метод First(). Но в случае с Dictionary, как правильно сказал @Etki, порядок ключей не гарантируется внутри последовательности и поэтому теоретически первым может стать любой элемент.

[SOverflow: whos on dictionary first](http://stackoverflow.com/a/437429)

Comment: @Etki: `dict.GetEnumerator().Current` недостаточно, т. к. `Enumerator` нужно ещё за-`Dispose`-ить. Правильно было бы

    using (var enum = dict.GetEnumerator())
        first = enum.Current;

(но тогда лучше уж воспользоваться `First()`).

Comment: @VladD, я не трогал c# больше года, я просто в доку заглянул )

Comment: @Etki: В любом случае, порядок не гарантирован.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем так. В C++ словарь отсортирован, и `first()` выдаёт пару с минимальным ключом.

Если вам нужнo такое же поведение, как в C++ (то есть минимальный ключ), воспользуйтесь конструкцией

```
var minKey = dict.Keys.Min();
var value = dict[minKey];
```

Если вам нужен именно первый добавленный элемент, вам нужно, например, параллельно к `Dictionary` держать `Queue<string>` ключей в порядке добавления. (Один ключ держать недостаточно, т. к. его могут удалить.)

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, Вам нужен [OrderedDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: +1. но тогда лучше уж [`SortedDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), он типизированный.

Comment: Я так понимаю, ТС хотел получать элементы в том порядке, в каком они добавлялись, а в SortedDictionary они упорядочиваются по ключам.